# Using WinJS with Angular2

Tags: winjs, angular

Trying to use a property to configure a WinJS control from within Angular2, so far I couldn't find a solution, e.g. this code below is throwing 'Can't bind to 'dataWinOptions' since it isn't a known property of the '' element'.

```
@View({
    template: `<div id="rating" data-win-control='WinJS.UI.Rating' [data-win-options]='jsonRating'></div>`
})
class MyRating {
    rating: number;
    get jsonRating() {
        return '{averageRating: ' + this.rating + '}';
    } 
    constructor() {
        this.rating = 1.5;
    }
}
```

Any hint?

Comment: Try this plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/aTd2x8?p=preview

Comment: I understand you created a class to add the property 'dataWinOptions' to the 'div' tag. However I want to use several of the WinJS controls which all use a different configuration model through the same 'data-win-options' property.

Comment: E.g. what would happen if I also want to also configure the 'data-win-options' from within Angular2 for this other WinJS control? `<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" [data-win-options]='jsonListOptions'></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ericdes about your last comment I think this would be the best option. Assuming you have Nth WinJS controls

Consider the following code. I'm specifying differents values for the `averageRating` property in `options`.

```
<winjs-control [options]="{averageRating: '1.5', someMoreOptions : 'x'}"></winjs-control>
<winjs-control [options]="{averageRating: '1.4', differentOptionsForThisOne :'Z'}"></winjs-control>
<winjs-control [options]="{averageRating: '1.3'}"></winjs-control>
<winjs-control [options]="{averageRating: '1.2'}"></winjs-control>
<winjs-control [options]="{averageRating: '1.1'}"></winjs-control>
// more and more...
```

The component will read this `options` property and will pass it to the view. Forget about the directive, it isn't necessary after all.
We pass options through `attr.data-win-options` since it isn't a property of div but an attribute.

```js
@Component({
  selector : 'winjs-control',
  properties : ['options']
})
@View({
  template : `<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Rating" [attr.data-win-options]="jsonRating"></div>`,
})
class WinJSComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}

  // We specify onInit so we make sure 'options' exist, at constructor time it would be undefined 
  // And we stringify it or otherwise it will pass an object, we need to convert it to a string
  onInit() {
    this.jsonRating = JSON.stringify(this.options);
  }

  // We process WinJS after view has been initialized
  // this is necessary or 'data-win-options' won't be fully processed
  // and it will fail silently...
  afterViewInit() {
    WinJS.UI.processAll();
  }
}
```

Here's a [plnkr for this case](http://plnkr.co/edit/EFT8oe?p=preview).

That's one option and IMHO I think this is the easiest one. Another one, having the same HTML content, would be to communicate the parent with its children and I haven't tested your case with that approach.

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks to the magic 'attr' in 'attr.data-win-options' I can set the options at will. I haven't seen it documented though... what does this 'attr' mean?

Comment: Here's a [cheatsheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19jHbsXeYj2QiZ-cGS_mA3nyaU86gLeonjU2Tfzm1J5Y/edit), and these issues : [#4438](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4438) and [#773](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/773)